# is there a way to access a Kubernetes service (externally) using just a name instead of node_name:port?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm running Jenkins on my K8s cluster, and it's currently accessible externally by node_name:port. Some of my users are bothered by accessing the service using a port name, is there a way I could just assign the service a name? for instance: jenkins.mydomain

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your suggestions, I forgot to mention that my k8s is running on bare-metal so, a solution like ingress on its own won't work.

I ended up using metallb for this.

https://metallb.universe.tf/

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Kubernetes Ingress. 
You can define rules that point internally to the Kubernetes Service in front of Jenkins.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Ingress or a Service of type LoadBalancer that listens on port 80 and forwards to the Jenkins Pods with the custom port. Then you could just create a DNS, for example for `jenkins.mydomain.com`, record pointing to the IP address of the Service.

Comment: LoadBalancer is not a good idea since it doesn't provide HTTPS out of the box like Ingress, instead